# scraping some dynamic data over and over (a browser like scraper!!)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, scrapy, scrapy-splash

i want to scrape some data from two bet websites. (that using javascript.)
these websites data is completely dynamic so they change minutes by minutes. and i need a web scraper to scrape these data and store it in a database. (each site just 5 games and for 12 hours.)

but the problem is this: when a scraper wants to extract data from web pages, it crawls into the first page and after that it finished the job, it'll close the first page and go to the second page and do it until last page.
if i scrape data in this way, i should send too much requests to the site and probably will get banned!

so i think there might be another way to do this: like a browser, if there were a scraper that opens some tabs and prevent these tabs from suspending and losing connection, data on those tabs would be updated automatically and will extracted simply + the websites won't ban it!

so i want to know is there any scraper like this? can selenium/splash + scrapy do something like this? or i should look for something else? (something like browser extensions?)
do you have any suggestions for me? :(

thanks and sorry for grammatical problems. :[[

Answer (score 0):

Use scrapy/splash and read this. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned